# How can I change picture on opening & closing details/summary?

Tags: javascript, html, html-tag-details

This is my first JavaScript ever. It took lots of time but can't get it to work.

Obviously, what it should do is changing the picture when the 'details/summary' part is opened. FYI it's a follow-up from [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70634302/html-combining-lazy-loading-summary?noredirect=1#comment124898628_70634302) that I'm trying to solve. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```html
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(a) {
      document.getElementById("img").src = a;
    }
    details.addEventListener("toggle", event => {
      if (details.open) {
        changeImage("https://via.placeholder.com/50/ff0000");
      } else {
        changeImage("https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000ff");
      }
    });
  </script>

  <details>
    <summary>
      <table>
        <td width="64">#910</td>
      </table>
    </summary>
    <table>
      <td width="64">#910</td>
    </table>
  </details>

  <img id="img" src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'>
</body>
```

Comment: When your script executes, the DOM in your page is still not ready. Put the script tag before the closing `</body>` tag and try again... Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load

Comment: @JordiNebot I tried that (also before posting this topic but then again) but doesn't work either. Edit: thanks for the link however, i added to my favs:-)

Comment: That's one problem but there are others... e.g. `details` is not defined in your script. Try `document.getElementsByTagName("details")[0].addEventListener(...` instead

Comment: You'll want to get in the habit of having your browser console open as you work on JavaScript. Here it's fairly apparent what's wrong. See the snippet demo I added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is your missing part: `const details = document.querySelector('details')`. Then it would work.

```js
    function changeImage(a) {
      document.getElementById("img").src = a;
    }
const details = document.querySelector('details')
    details.addEventListener("toggle", event => {
      if (details.open) {
        changeImage("https://via.placeholder.com/50/ff0000");
      } else {
        changeImage("https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000ff");
      }
    });
```

```html
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  </script>

  <details>
    <summary>
      <table>
        <td width="64">#910</td>
      </table>
    </summary>
    <table>
      <td width="64">#910</td>
    </table>
  </details>

  <img id="img" src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.currentTarget;`, it points to the tag that is listeneing for the event. That event is a simple 'click', never read that 'toggle' was an event, I learned something today.

```js
const changeImage = event => {
  const clicked = event.currentTarget;
  const img = document.querySelector('.img');

  if (clicked.matches('details')) {
    if (clicked.open) {
      img.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/50/ff0000";
    } else {
      img.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000ff";
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('details').addEventListener('click', changeImage)
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <table>
      <td width="64">#910</td>
    </table>
  </summary>
  <table>
    <td width="64">#910</td>
  </table>
</details>
<img class="img" src='https://via.placeholder.com/50'>
```